# parse string with regualr expression with version number in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string in two different format like following how to I write a RegExp in js to parse the information to get `appName1-v10.20.` under `Package:` ?

```
//example string
const twoMatchString = '\[Package: [appName1-v10.20.1](https://github.com/appName1/1111), [appName2-v20.15.10](https://github.com/appName2/aaa)\]\r\n[asdsad: asdas]\r\ni am description on PR'
const oneMatchString = '[Package: appName1-v10.20.1](https://github.com/appName1/1111)\r\n[asdsad: asdas]\r\ni am description on PR'
 
const reg = /\[Package:\s?(.+?,?)\]/g
const twoMatch = twoMatchString.matchAll(reg);
const oneMatch = oneMatchString.matchAll(reg);
console.log(twoMatch ) // wish to have ["appName1-v10.20.1", "appName2-v20.15.10"] 
console.log(oneMatch) // wish to have ["appName1-v10.20.1"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `matchAll` returns an `RegExpStringIterator`.

On [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) there are examples how to get the values into an array using `Array.from`

If a positive lookbehind is supported ([see this page](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) for browser support):

```
(?<=\[Package:.*?)[^\s\][-]+-[^\][]+(?=])
```

- `(?<=\[Package:.*?)` Assert `[Package:` to the left
- `[^\s\][-]+` Match a non whitspace char other than `[` `]` `-` or whitespace char
- `-` Match `-`
- `[^\][]+` Match 1+ times any char other than `[` and `]`
- `(?=])` Positive lookahead to assert a `]` to the right.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u7CF7l/1)

```js
const oneMatchString = '\[Package: [appName1-v10.20.1](https://github.com/appName1/1111), [appName2-v20.15.10](https://github.com/appName2/aaa)\]\r\n[asdsad: asdas]\r\ni am description on PR'
const twoMatchString = '[Package: [appName1-v10.20.1](https://github.com/appName1/1111)\r\n[asdsad: asdas]\r\ni am description on PR'

const reg = /(?<=\[Package:.*?)[^\s\][-]+-[^\][]+(?=])/g;

const twoMatch = Array.from(twoMatchString.matchAll(reg), s => s[0]);
const oneMatch = Array.from(oneMatchString.matchAll(reg), s => s[0]);

console.log(twoMatch) //["appName1-v10.20.1", "appName2-v20.15.10"] 
console.log(oneMatch) // ["appName1-v10.20.1"]
```

Or a bit more strict version

```
(?<=\[Package:.*?)[^\s-]+-v\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?=])
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CkAnN2/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
const extract = (text) => {
  const package = /\[Package:((?:,?\s*\[?[^\][]+]\([^()]*\))*)/.exec(text)?.[1]
  return package ? 
     Array.from(package.matchAll(/(?:^|\[)([^\][]*-v\d[^\][]*)]/g), x => x[1].trim()) : ""
}
```

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const extract = (text) => {
  const package = /\[Package:((?:,?\s*\[?[^\][]+]\([^()]*\))*)/.exec(text)?.[1]
  return package ? 
     Array.from(package.matchAll(/(?:^|\[)([^\][]*-v\d[^\][]*)]/g), x => x[1].trim()) : ""
}

const oneMatchString = '\[Package: [appName1-v10.20.1](https://github.com/appName1/1111), [appName2-v20.15.10](https://github.com/appName2/aaa)\]\r\n[asdsad: asdas]\r\ni am description on PR'
const twoMatchString = '[Package: appName1-v10.20.1](https://github.com/appName1/1111)\r\n[asdsad: asdas]\r\ni am description on PR'

console.log( extract(oneMatchString) ) // ["appName1-v10.20.1", "appName2-v20.15.10"] 
console.log( extract(twoMatchString) ) // ["appName1-v10.20.1"]
```

The `\[Package:((?:,?\s*\[?[^\][]+]\([^()]*\))*)` [regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/QRUevj/1/)

- `\[Package:` - `[Package:` string
- `((?:,?\s*\[?[^\][]+]\([^()]*\))*)` - Group 1: zero or more occurrences of the following pattern sequences:

  - `,?\s*` - an optional `,` and zero or more whitespaces
  - `\[?` - an optional `[`
  - `[^\][]+` - one or more chars other than `[` and `]`
  - `]\(` -  `](` string
  - `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - a `)` char.

The `(?:^|\[)([^\][]*-v\d[^\][]*)]` [regex extracts](https://regex101.com/r/QRUevj/2) the versions:

- `(?:^|\[)` - string start or `[`
- `([^\][]*-v\d[^\][]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`, `-v`, a digit and again any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.